# Angular 11 TypeError: Cannot add property x, object is not extensible

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have been working to solve a problem that is about pushing a new item to an array that is called **Comments**. There was no problem in previous Angular versions, but I am getting an error for Angular 11.

I have a reducer that is called PostReducer. When an user creates a post comment, I need to update my state.

I can not update **a comment array** of a Post.
It says

**core.js:6150 ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 18, object is not extensible
at Array.push ()**

How can I solve this problem?

Here is PostComment model.

```
        export class PostComment {
        Id: number;
        text: string;
        createdByUserName: string;
        createdByUserPhoto: string;
        createdDate: Date;
        postId: number;
    }
```

Here is Post model.

```
        import { PostComment } from "./postComment";

        export class Post {
            Id: number;
            text: string;
            createdByUserName: string;
            createdByUserPhoto: string;
            imageUrlList: string[] = [];
            videoUrl: string;
            createdDate: Date;
            postType: number;
            comments: PostComment[] = [];
            fancyboxData: string;
        }
```

Here is my PostState implementations.

```
        export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
        posts: PostState;
      }

    export interface PostState {
        showPostId: boolean;
        currentPost: Post;
        currentPostId: number;
        posts: Post[];
        commentPost: Post;
        isNewPost: boolean;
        error: string;
        isNewComment: boolean;
    }

    const initialState: PostState = {
        showPostId: true,
        currentPost: null,
        currentPostId: null,
        posts: [],
        commentPost: null,
        isNewPost: false,
        error: '',
        isNewComment: false
    };
```

Here is my PostActionTypes.CreateCommentSuccess in postReducer

```
  case PostActionTypes.CreateCommentSuccess:
        let post: Post = state.posts.filter((item: any) => item.id == action.payload.postId[0];
        post.comments.push(action.payload);
        return {
            ...state,
            posts: [...state.posts, post],
            error: '',
            isNewComment: false
        };
```

CreateCommentSuccess action type implementation.

```
export class CreateCommentSuccess implements Action {
readonly type = PostActionTypes.CreateCommentSuccess;

constructor(public payload: PostComment) { }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: The state is immutable here. So in your reducer use let post: Post = […state.posts.filter((item: any) => item.id == action.payload.postId[0]];

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by editing PostActionTypes.CreateCommentSuccess action type reducer. I took advantage of the page I shared below.

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/deeply-nested-objectives-redux

```
case PostActionTypes.CreateCommentSuccess:
        const postIndex: number = state.posts.findIndex((item: any) => item.id == action.payload.postId);
        return {
            ...state,
            posts: [{
                ...state.posts[postIndex],
                comments: [...state.posts[postIndex].comments, action.payload]
            }],
            error: '',
            isNewComment: false
        };
```